# how to use strtok to print a binary number?

Tags: c, input, whitespace, scanf, strtok

So im trying to get a binary number from using the strtok function to iterate through a user inputted string. If the user inputs alpha it prints a 0 and if the user inputs beta it will output a 1.So if a user types in "alpha beta alpha beta alpha" the output should be "01010". I have the following code but im not sure where im going wrong as it is not doing the behavior i described

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char userinput[250];
    long binaryarray[250];
    char *token;
    int counter = 0;
    long binarynumber = 0 ;
    printf("enter alpha or beta");
    scanf("%s", userinput);
    token = strtok(userinput, " ");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        if(!strcmp(token, "alpha"))
        {
            binaryarray[counter] = 0;
            counter += 1;
        }
        if(!strcmp(token, "beta"))
        {
            binaryarray[counter] = 1;
            counter += 1;
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, " \0");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        binarynumber = 10 * binarynumber + binaryarray[i];
    }
    printf("%ld", binarynumber);
}
```

How would I fix this issue?

Comment: alright i just posted the actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said by @SouravGhosh you should use `fgets` to store the whole string inserted by user with white spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char userinput[250] = {0};
    char binaryarray[250];
    char* token;
    size_t counter = 0;

    printf("enter alpha or beta");
    fgets(userinput, sizeof(userinput), stdin);

    token = strtok(userinput, " \n\0");

    while (( token != NULL) && (count < sizeof(binaryarray)))
    {
        if(!strcmp(token,"alpha"))
        {
            binaryarray[counter] = '0';
            counter++;
        }
        else if(!strcmp(token,"beta"))
        {
            binaryarray[counter] = '1';
            counter++;
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, " \n\0");
    }

    for(size_t i=0 ; i< counter; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", binaryarray[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

But you have other problems:

1. Your tokens should be `" \n\0"` to match all possible chars between words.
2. All tokens must be checked with the first strok in case of a single input, so no whitespaces
3. Using an int to calculate your "binary" and print it with `"%ld"` format specifier does not print leading zeros. You can directly store chars into the buffer.

Comment: also so how would i revise the code so that it always prints a 1 first for the binary number regardless of whether alpha or beta is called. So for example alpha beta would be in binary 101 and beta beta alpha would be 1110

Comment: char binaryarray[250] = {'1'}; int counter = 1;

Comment: is there an email i can ask you a question through? for some reason im having some issues and im not allowed to post all of my code due to academic policies.

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to publish any of my e-mail account. Try to reproduce your code with a different code and post it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, for

```
  scanf("%s",userinput);
```

the *scanning* stops after encountering the first whitespace. So, it cannot scan and store an input like

> *alpha beta alpha beta alpha*

separated by whitespace. Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2

> `s`
>
> Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters.

**Possible Solution:** You need to use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read the user input with whitespaces.

Comment: And the leading zeros will not be printed. It would be better to construct a string of `'0'` and `'1'` characters than convert to a decimal that is supposed to look like a binary number.

Comment: Or to just print the digits as you go instead of storing them up to print all at once at the end.

Comment: @JohnBollinger so I just tried putting print statements after the strcmp functions and its still only printing out 1 digit

Comment: @h101 was that *after* making the change suggested in this answer?

Comment: alright yea the fgets ended up fixing my problem and its now working as intended